# Moved wordpress site, image links are all broken

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess

Got an issue with a wordpress site that I've never experienced before. I have moved a site for a client from one server to another (I've done this several times before). The site has moved fine, however none of the images from my uploads folder are displaying. When I check the link, there is no "/" before wp-content, so my link reads like this:

http://www.vimartech.co.ukwp-content/uploads/2014/03/VIMARTECH-INDUSTRIAL.jpg

Here is my .htaccess file which is where I believe the issue lies. Can anyone help me out please.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because wordpress holds full path to image in it's database.
This also true for configuration entries.

I haven't used wordpress for some time, but in the past [I used a simple search/replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to change old domain to new at doployment stage.

Comment: Perfect. I did use a search and replace - but didn't add a "/" to the end of the URL